# Android facebook - Why the permission is "disappear" after the user cancel in permission dialog?

Tags: android, facebook, session, permissions

The workflow is like this:

user click on login-> after login success-> prompt permission dialog, if accept , logined, if cancel, open the box again next time

The problem is , for the first time the permission dialog has request the email permission, however, if the user click on cancel and open the box later, the email permission seems no longer exist, it just ask user for their personal info.

How to fix this? Thanks

Update: I try to fix the code, however, it throw exception and it seems related to the flow logic. How to fix this? I will provide the very detail of my code , thanks for helping.

**The modification:**

1. Added `private final static List<String> PERMISSIONS = Arrays.asList("email");`
2. update onclickLogin()

   ```
   private void onClickLogin() {
   Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
   List<String> permissions = session.getPermissions();

   Log.d("test1","p:" + permissions);
   Log.d("test1","session open" + session.isOpened());

   if (!session.isOpened() && !session.isClosed()) {
       Log.d("test1","test1");
       session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(this).setPermissions("email").setCallback(statusCallback));
   } else if(!isSubset(PERMISSIONS, permissions)) {
       Log.d("test1","test2");
       Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissions = new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(this, PERMISSIONS);
       session.requestNewPublishPermissions(newPermissions); 
   } else {
       Log.d("test1","test3");
       Session.openActiveSession(getActivity(), this, true, statusCallback);
   }
   ```

   }
3. added isSubset()

**The log cat output**

```
03-09 14:30:29.301: D/test1(23828): p:[]
03-09 14:30:29.301: D/test1(23828): session openfalse
03-09 14:30:29.301: D/test1(23828): test1
03-09 14:30:42.654: D/test1(23828): p:[]
03-09 14:30:42.654: D/test1(23828): session openfalse
03-09 14:30:42.654: D/test1(23828): test2
```

The exception

```
03-09 14:30:42.694: E/AndroidRuntime(23828): java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Session: an attempt was made to request new permissions for a session that has been closed.
```

Notes: it seems after clicking cancel and open the box for the second time, the session is still not opened so I removed the Session.isopened checking. Otherwise it only fall into the third condition

Here is the full code of the Class:

```
public class Home extends Fragment implements LoginListener {
    private final static String TAG = "Home";
    public View rootView;
    public ImageView HomeBg;
    public ImageView buttonLoginLogout;
    public TextView chi;
    public TextView eng;
    public ColorStateList oldColor;
    public SharedPreferences prefs;
    public EasyTracker tracker = null;
    public SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    public ProgressDialog pd;
    public Home ctx;

    //Facebook login
    private Session.StatusCallback statusCallback = new SessionStatusCallback();
    private final static List<String> PERMISSIONS = Arrays.asList("email");

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        ctx = this;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        try{
            // fix for disable the hiding action bar animation
            getActivity().getActionBar().getClass().getDeclaredMethod("setShowHideAnimationEnabled", boolean.class).invoke(getActivity().getActionBar(), false);
        } catch (Exception exception){
            // animation will be run if not support
        }

        getActivity().getActionBar().hide();

        tracker = EasyTracker.getInstance(getActivity());

        prefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("userInfo", 0);
        editor = prefs.edit();

        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home, container, false);
        buttonLoginLogout = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.home_connectFB);
        eng = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn_eng);
        chi = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn_chi);

        eng.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                if (!Utility.getLocale(getActivity()).equals("en")) {
                    tracker.send(MapBuilder.createEvent("menu_click","language", "switchEN", null).build());
                    chi.setTextColor(oldColor);
                    eng.setTextColor(getActivity().getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));
                    MyApp.updateLanguage(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "en");
                    refreshAfterLocaleChanged("en");
                }
            }
        });

        chi.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                if (!Utility.getLocale(getActivity()).equals("zh")) {
                    tracker.send(MapBuilder.createEvent("menu_click","language", "switchTC", null).build());
                    eng.setTextColor(oldColor);
                    chi.setTextColor(getActivity().getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));
                    MyApp.updateLanguage(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "zh");
                    refreshAfterLocaleChanged("zh");
                }
            }
        });

        if (Utility.getLocale(getActivity()).equals("zh")) {
            chi.setTextColor(getActivity().getResources().getColor(
                    android.R.color.white));
            oldColor = eng.getTextColors();
        } else {
            eng.setTextColor(getActivity().getResources().getColor(
                    android.R.color.white));
            oldColor = chi.getTextColors();

        }

        //Facebook login
        Settings.addLoggingBehavior(LoggingBehavior.INCLUDE_ACCESS_TOKENS);

        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (session == null) {
            if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                session = Session.restoreSession(getActivity(), null, statusCallback, savedInstanceState);
            }
            if (session == null) {
                session = new Session(getActivity());
            }
            Session.setActiveSession(session);
            if (session.getState().equals(SessionState.CREATED_TOKEN_LOADED)) {
               // session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(this).setPermissions(Arrays.asList("basic_info","email")).setCallback(statusCallback));
                session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(this).setPermissions("email").setCallback(statusCallback));
            }
        }

       updateView();

       return rootView;
    }

    public void refreshAfterLocaleChanged(String lang){
        SharedPreferences langPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        Editor editor = langPrefs.edit();
        editor.putString("lang",lang).commit();

        Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
        getActivity().finish();
        getActivity().overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Session.getActiveSession().addCallback(statusCallback);
        tracker.set(Fields.SCREEN_NAME, "hk7app/CX/" + Utility.getLocale(getActivity()) + "/Landing Page");
        tracker.send(MapBuilder.createAppView().build());
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        if (pd != null)
            pd.dismiss();

        Session.getActiveSession().removeCallback(statusCallback);
        EasyTracker.getInstance(getActivity()).activityStop(getActivity());
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private void updateView() {
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (session.isOpened()) {
             final String token = session.getAccessToken();
             Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(GraphUser user,Response response) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        if (user != null) {
                            if (!user.getId().equals(prefs.getString("fbId",""))) {
                                editor.putString("fbId", user.getId());
                                editor.putString("fName", user.getFirstName());
                                editor.putString("lName", user.getLastName());
                                if (user.asMap() != null && user.asMap().get("email") != null) {
                                    editor.putString("email", user.asMap().get("email").toString());
                                }
                                editor.commit();
                            }
                            if (prefs.getString("memId","").equals("") || prefs.getString("token","").equals("") || !user.getId().equals(prefs.getString("fbId",""))){
                                pd = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.sys_info),getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.loading));
                                new APIHandler(getActivity(),tracker,"login",pd).execute(ctx,token);
                            } else {
                                onLoginComplete("","");
                            }
                        }
                    }
             });                  
        } else {
            buttonLoginLogout.setImageResource(R.drawable.landing_btn_connect_facebook);
            buttonLoginLogout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View view) { onClickLogin(); }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(getActivity(), requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        Session.saveSession(session, outState);
    }

    private void onClickLogin() {
        tracker.send(MapBuilder.createEvent("menu_click","Fbconnect","connectFB_" + Utility.getLocale(getActivity()),null).build());
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        List<String> permissions = session.getPermissions();// to get the session permissions

        Log.d("test1","p:" + permissions);
        Log.d("test1","session open" + session.isOpened());

        if (!session.isOpened() && !session.isClosed()) {
            Log.d("test1","test1");
            session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(this).setPermissions("email").setCallback(statusCallback));
        } else if(!isSubset(PERMISSIONS, permissions)) {
            Log.d("test1","test2");
            Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissions = new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(this, PERMISSIONS);
            session.requestNewPublishPermissions(newPermissions); 
        } else {
            Log.d("test1","test3");
            Session.openActiveSession(getActivity(), this, true, statusCallback);
        }
    }

    //this function is to check if the user has a specific permission within the session
    private boolean isSubset(Collection<String> subset, Collection<String> superset) {
        for (String string : subset) {
            if(!superset.contains(string))
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private class SessionStatusCallback implements Session.StatusCallback {
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
            Log.d(TAG,"SessionStatusCallback");
            if (exception != null) {
                Log.d(TAG,""+exception);

                if (!session.isClosed()) {
                   session.closeAndClearTokenInformation(); //reset session
                   Session.setActiveSession(null);
                }

                if (exception instanceof FacebookAuthorizationException){
                    new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                    .setTitle(ctx.getResources().getString(R.string.sys_info))
                    .setMessage(R.string.facebook_permission_missing)
                    .setPositiveButton(ctx.getResources().getString(R.string.close), null)
                    .show();
                }
            } else {
                updateView();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        AppEventsLogger.activateApp(getActivity(),getResources().getString(R.string.app_id));
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoginComplete(String memberId, String token) {    
        if (pd != null)
            pd.dismiss();

        if (!memberId.equals("") && !token.equals("")) {
            editor.putString("memId", memberId);
            editor.putString("token", token);
            editor.commit();
        }

        buttonLoginLogout.setImageResource(R.drawable.landing_btn_take_a_selfie);
        buttonLoginLogout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                 tracker.send(MapBuilder.createEvent("menu_click","TakeSelfie","Selfie_now_" + Utility.getLocale(getActivity()),null).build());
                ((LandingPage)getActivity()).tabHost.setCurrentTab(2);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoginFailure(String errorMsg) {
        if (pd != null)
            pd.dismiss();

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course because the session is already exists... so the else will be called.. you need to check if the permission exists in the active session..

add the following:..

```
private final static List<String> PERMISSIONS = Arrays.asList("email");
```

then within 'onClickLogin' add to the if-else statement block..

```
List<String> permissions = session.getPermissions();// to get the session permissions
else if(session.isOpened() && !isSubset(PERMISSIONS, permissions) {
   Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissions = new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(this, PERMISSIONS);
   session.requestNewPublishPermissions(newPermissions); 
}
```

the `isSubset` function

```
//this function is to check if the user has a specific permission within the session
private boolean isSubset(Collection<String> subset, Collection<String> superset) {
    for (String string : subset) {
        if(!superset.contains(string))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

this is a general idea of how the to show message every time the user access the activity (if you are using `uiLifeCycleHelper`), so you still need to modify it more to meet your needs.

Comment: Thanks, I am not using uiLifeCycleHelper, I modify the code according to the SessionLoginExample of the offical facebook sample project

Comment: Also, I put more detail of my code in the updated question, please have a look, I found the session.getPermissions() always return empty list, is it the root cause of the problem? Thanks

Comment: try to add `session = Session.getActiveSession();` before getting the list of permissions.

Comment: Please wait a moment , it seems it is still can not get permission, I am going to post the updated code

Comment: I have updated the question, the session is not opened when I click the login button for the second time.  please have a look if any detail is missing?

Answer (score 0):

When user press cancel button on the permission for the first time, session never gets opened and also session doesn't get closed normally.It returns "CLOSED_LOGIN_FAILED" as the value of the Session's state field.You can check this by:  session.getState().toString();
That's why your else if block is not working for one reason.
Second,when I executed the newPermission statement it gave me an error, as obviously the session needs to be opened before setting a permission.

So, the following has worked for me:
Within onClickLogin(), add the following code into else if block:

```
    else if(session.getState().toString().equals("CLOSED_LOGIN_FAILED") && !isSubset(PERMISSIONS, permissions)){
      Log.v("LoginType","Login+PermissionsforCancelledTimes");

      Session.openActiveSession( Login.this, true, Arrays.asList("public_profile","email") ,statusCallback);
}
```